# Doctrine doesn't create a foreign key with many-to-one association between mapped superclasses?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, symfony-2.1

I have two mapped superclasses `AbstractItem` and `AbstractTemplate`, with a many-to-one unidirectional association:

```
Me\Core\Entity\AbstractItem:
  type: mappedSuperclass
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  manyToOne:
    template:
      targetEntity: AbstractTemplate

Me\Core\Entity\AbstractTemplate:
  type: mappedSuperclass
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
```

Actual classses `Section` and `Template` extend their abstract counterparts. When I dump the SQL (`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete`) i get:

```sql
CREATE TABLE section (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    position SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    template_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX IDX_2D737AEF5DA0FB8 (template_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE template (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
```

... and the foreign key `section.template_id` to `template.id` isn't created. Any idea? I'm using Doctrine 2.3.*.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen the way you want.
From here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a  mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many > associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all. Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance features have to be used.

Doctrine is only going to map entities.  AbstractEntities don't actually exist so nothing to map.  I'm surprised that you were able to even get temple_id from what you mosted.

You will need to establish the relation in your section.yml and template.yml files.

And yes if you derive other entities from your abstract classes then you will need to add the relation on them as well.

============================================

UPDATE: More info for the comment.

You can define the association between an abstract class and an actual entity class. In you yaml file use Template instead of AbstractTemplate.  Any entities derived from the abstract class will inherit the relation but it will always point to a Template entity.

So you could have

Section manyToOne Template
Page    manyToOne Template

where both Section and Page extend AbstractItem

When you try to point to an AbstractTemplate the system has no idea which actual derives AbstractTemplate class to point to.  There could be a dozen derived classes.

So if you want any AbstractItem derives entity to be able to point to any AbstractTemplate derives class then you will need to define the relation in the derived AbstractItem entity.

Hope that answers the question.

Wait a second.  Now I understand your confusion.  You got a template_id in your table because you named the relation template.  I would have expected and error to have been generated during doctrine:schema:update because of pointing to AbstractTemplate which is not an entity.  Might be a bug in doctrine.

==============================================

Update #2

Took the dogs for a walk and came up with a guess as to what it was your were actually trying to accomplish.

I'm guesing that you want some of your sectionItems linked to one type of template (call it TemplateType1) and other sectionItems linked to a different type of template (calls it TemplateType2)?

If this is indeed the case then you want to use table inheritance for your templates.  Your AbstractItem.template.targetEntity will then be BaseTeamplate instead of AbstractTemplate.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

If this is not what you trying to do then consider updating your question and adding what you really are trying to achieve.

Comment: So many-to-one is an allowed association. What's the point of let me define this association in the mapped superclass, if the foreign key is not created? Defining `manyToOne` to create `template_id` is exactly the same as defining `template_id` as a regular field... confused about the point.

Answer (score 0):

So you really didn't specify anything here with the many-to-one relationship.

try this:

```
Me\Core\Entity\AbstractItem:
  type: mappedSuperclass
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  manyToOne:
    template:
      targetEntity: AbstractTemplate
      joinColumn: 
         name: Ab_template #dont want to create a naming issue
         referencedColumnName: id
```

Let me know what happens after. Remember to run `schema:update`!

Comment: Still doesn't work. And as per documentation, joinColumn configuration is not mandatory.